# Отсутствует PropertyExpression

Tags: c#, lambda, expressions, деревья-выражений

Пробую написать простой пример на с использованием Expressions, но получаю странную ошибку: не могу использовать `PropertyExpression` во время компиляции.
Когда я указываю это имя я получаю ошибку и код не компилируется

[image]

Но в рантайме на точке остановки я могу написать

```
var runtimeBody = (System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression)body2;
```

и это срабатывает, происходит каст как и задумывалось.

Использую фреймворк 4.5.1.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [PropertyExpression is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29962398/5752652) от участника  [@Alex Zhukovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2559709/alex-zhukovskiy).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29962398

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что `PropertyExpression` объявлено с модификатором internal

[Этот пост](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab528f6a-a60e-4af6-bf31-d58e3f373356/resolving-propertyexpressions-and-fieldexpressions-in-a-custom-linq-provider?forum=linqprojectgeneral) предлагает вам делать каст к  `System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression`.

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [PropertyExpression is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29962398/5752652) от участника  [@Sébastien Sevrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4840746/s%c3%a9bastien-sevrin).</sub>

Comment: Или BinaryExpression для LogicalBinaryExpression